# Center Text inside Button and reduce button padding

Tags: android, xml, button

[image: pic]

My button is "ADD" and as you can see the text doesn't fit inside and it is cut on the buttom part , I think that the white space around the text inside the button is too big and that's why i can't fit it.
I don't want to lower its size ..

My button in xml:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/exp_routine"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:alpha="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Routine"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="#686868"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />




    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_add"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:minWidth="0dp"
        android:minHeight="0dp"
        android:stateListAnimator="@null"
        android:text="add"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:includeFontPadding="false"
        android:textAlignment="gravity"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/exp_routine"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: can you post the whole xml code?

Comment: plz post the root layout

Comment: either reduce the `textSize` or try adding `android:includeFontPadding="false"` to the button

Comment: android:includeFontPadding="false"  moved it up by a little

Comment: I added the root layout

Comment: please share the xml of  `style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton"` also

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apart from

```
android:minWidth="0dp"
android:minHeight="0dp"
```

you need to set `includeFontPadding` to `false` and `padding` to `0dp` so you can create new style and use it as

```
 <style name="NoPaddingTextButton" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton">
        <item name="android:padding">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:includeFontPadding">false</item>
 </style>
```

and use it

```
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_add"
        style="@style/NoPaddingTextButton"
        ...
 />
```

Note: You might still see extra padding at top and bottom but that is for characters like `p` or `'` etc, you can verify it with

```
    android:text="ADD p '`"
```

Answer (score 1):

In the code your `ConstraintLayout` height is predefined `android:layout_height="40dp"` this is what causes the clipping as the  height of the button is more.

Change to `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` if suitable or even `android:layout_height="match_parent"` will work in the case its a root layout

Answer (score 1):

> I try to modify your layout and this one works for me. I have added padding manually and removed this style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton".
>   Please post this style code if this answer won't work.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/exp_routine"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:alpha="1"
        android:text="Routine"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="#686868"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />




    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_add"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:minWidth="0dp"
        android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
        android:minHeight="0dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:text="add"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/exp_routine"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/exp_routine"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/exp_routine" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```